# Need help in list manipulations

Tags: list-manipulation

```
list1={{"a",{"a1","a2","a3","a4"}},(*{"b",{"b1"}},*){"c",{"c1","c2","c3","c4"}}}

list2={{"a",{"aa1","aa2","aa3"}},{"b",{"bb1","bb2","bb3","bb4"}},{"c",{"cc1","cc2","cc3"}}}
```

how to get this from above lists:

```
{{"a",{"a1","a2","a3","a4","aa1","aa2","aa3"}},{"b",{(*"b1",*)"bb1","bb2","bb
3","bb4"}},{"c",{"c1","c2","c3","c4","cc1","cc2","cc3"}}}
```

???

Comment: Welcome!  A terse verbose description of what you want to achieve would be useful in addition. The more effort you invest in your question, the more likely you will get good answers.

Comment: someone asked me to solve this challenge. All I want is what should I do with first two lists to get the third list.

Comment: For example to get the first element of the resulting list all I need to do is take union(may be once or twice) of first element of both lists .

Comment: Where I am stuck is in second element there is a comment (*. How to get rid of it.

Comment: You will not be able to keep comments during manipulation unless you convert everything to strings. Comments will be ignored / stripped in interpretation.

Comment: According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_(computer_programming)): In computer programming, a comment is a programmer-readable annotation in the source code of a computer program. They are added with the purpose of making the source code easier to understand, and are generally **ignored by compilers and interpreters**. For your purpose, you might need [`Style`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) or the new-in-v10.4 [`Highlighted`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Highlighted.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

With `GroupBy` plus using `Highlighted` from @xzczd comment above.

```
list1 = {{"a", {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"}}, {"b", {Highlighted@"b1"}}, 
         {"c", {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"}}}
list2 = {{"a", {"aa1", "aa2", "aa3"}}, {"b", {"bb1", "bb2", "bb3", "bb4"}}, 
         {"c", {"cc1", "cc2", "cc3"}}}

KeyValueMap[{#1, Union @@ #2} &] @ GroupBy[Join[list1, list2], First -> Last]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using `GatherBy[]`

```
list1 = {{"a", {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"}}, {"b", {"b1"}}, 
         {"c", {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"}}}

list2 = {{"a", {"aa1", "aa2", "aa3"}}, {"b", {"bb1", "bb2", "bb3", "bb4"}},
         {"c", {"cc1", "cc2", "cc3"}}}


{#1[[1]], Join[#1[[2]], #2[[2]]]} & @@@ GatherBy[Join[list1, list2], First]
```

Or

```
Join[list1, list2, 2] /. {x_, y_, x_, z_} :> {x, Join[y, z]}
```

> ```
> {{"a", {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "aa1", "aa2", "aa3"}}, 
>  {"b", {"b1", "bb1", "bb2", "bb3", "bb4"}}, 
>  {"c", {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "cc1","cc2", "cc3"}}}
> ```

Comment: , sir there is a comment in the first list that needs to be added back in the result.

Comment: Can anyone help please!?